# Необходимо перенести все элементы из массива объектов класса в XElements

Tags: c#, linq2xml

У меня есть xml файл, который выглядит следующим образом:

```xml
<dialog>
    <name>5</name>
    <onEvent type="quest" status="completed">2</onEvent>
    <disposable>true</disposable>
    <replic>
        <character>frost</character>
        <message>Вот так, просыпайтесь, мисс Хоуп.</message>
    </replic>
    <replic>
        <character>betty_hope</character>
        <message>Я ничего не понимаю. Доктор Мороу жив? Он с кем-то говорил...</message>
    </replic>
    <replic>
        <character>frost</character>
        <message>Вам почудилось, мисс. Доктор мертв. А у вас был шок.</message>
    </replic>
</dialog>
```

Я пытаюсь сделать редактор на С#, который бы позволял  мне добавлять и редактировать диалоги в этом файле. Сейчас у меня диалоги хранятся в массиве объектов класса Phrase. Сам класс представляет из себя 2 элемента типа string:

1. один для имени персонажа
2. другой для реплики.

Как используя Linq to XML добавить все элементы из массива в XML файл.

Answer (score 1):

Изменил способ задачи XElement, как раз таки через .Add и получил, что хотел.

```
XElement onEvent = new XElement("onEvent",task_name.Text.ToString());
onEvent.Add(new XAttribute("type", EventType.Text.ToString()));
onEvent.Add(new XAttribute("status", EventStatus.Text.ToString()));
dialog.Add(onEvent);

XElement name = new XElement("name", Dialog_name.Text.ToString());
dialog.Add(name);

XElement dissposable = new XElement("dissposable", testT);
dialog.Add(dissposable);

foreach (Phrase element in EndArray)
{
    XElement replic = new XElement("replic");
    XElement character = new XElement("character", element.get_char(element));
    replic.Add(character);

    XElement message = new XElement("message", element.get_phrase(element));
    replic.Add(message);

    dialog.Add(replic);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Добавить - никак. LINQ to XML - штука функциональная.
Но преобразовать диалог в XDocument можно, сделав примерно так:

```
var name = new XElement("name", dialog.Name);
var disposable = new XElement("disposable", dialog.Disposable);

var replics = dialog.Replics.Select(r =>
    new XElement("replic",
        new XElement("character", r.Character),
        new XElement("message", r.Message)
    )
);

var documentContent = new [] { name, disposable }
    .Concat(replics)
    .ToArray();

var document = new XDocument(
    new XElement("dialog", documentContent)
);
```

Comment: Да ну? А метод [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.add(v=vs.110).aspx) вроде как и не существует, да?